# mysql USER unclear about what can be dropped?

Tags: mysql

When `show databases` there is the `information_schema` below it listing my created databases but what is 'USER' and 'mysql' listed in there?

I don't know if ages ago I made a mistake and created them or if they are default listings which reveal something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you should have mysql database on your machine and mysql database should have the following tables:

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| ndb_binlog_index          |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| servers                   |
| slow_log                  |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also  you should have the following databases:

```
mysql> show databases;
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| performance_schema  |
| mysql               |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The databases `information_schema` and `mysql` are there by default. `information_schema` contains useful information about the status of your mysql server and the storage engines you are using, it is read only. The db `mysql` stores certain configurations of your MySQL server, like for exmample the users and their password hashes, it is editable.

I don't think the db `USER` that you are mentioning is one of the default dbs, so that would have to have been created by you.

Comment: thank you for the answer to that and you are both right but I am only allowed to select one answer.